# Question regarding pg_stat_reset() in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a question regarding function `pg_stat_reset();` I am trying to collect database table stats on regular basis and for that purpose i am using stats from various postgres tables like `pg_stat_all_tables, pg_stat_database`. But data in this table is accumulated over period of time. I am planning to reset it on daily basis. I just want to know if its safe to run this function on daily, hourly basis on production database. And also if safe are there any settings PG offer by which i can reset stats of regular interval, apart from setting cronjob and running `pg_stat_reset()`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: theoretically is safe, this just clean you statistics from `pg_stat*` tables

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it, it will interfere with proper functioning of autovacuum.  Rather than resetting counters to zero, just take snapshots of the counters and subtract one snapshot from a later one.